# Finding change of coordinates for 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the 1-form
$$\omega = pdq - \frac{p^2 + q^2}{2}dt $$
and have been trying to find a change of coordinates so that I can write $\omega$ as
$$\omega = PdQ - dT.$$
If I have found a change of coordinates in one direction, is there an easy way to determine the change of coordinates $p=(P,Q,T), q=(P,Q,T),t=(P,Q,T)$ in the other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your expressions, it is rather easy to invert the relations to get $(p,q,t)$ as a function of $(P, Q, T)$ (if this is what you are asking):

$$ p = \sqrt{-2P} \, ; \, q = \frac{-2T}{\sqrt{-2P}} \, ; \, t = Q + \frac{T}{P} \, .$$

---

Observe that your change of variables is not global. Indeed, looking at the formula for $Q$, it is clearly undefined for $p = 0$. In fact, your formulae define two diffeomorphisms

$$ \Psi_1 : (0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to (- \infty, 0) \times \mathbb{R}^2 : (p,q,t) \mapsto (P, Q, T) \, , \\
 \Psi_2 : (-\infty, 0) \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to (- \infty, 0) \times \mathbb{R}^2 : (p,q,t) \mapsto (P, Q, T) \, , $$

which are related by the relation $\Psi_1(p,q,t) = \Psi_2(-p,-q,t)$. Therefore, your formulae are unable to recover every triple $(P, Q, T)$. Depending on your applications, this may be a bad thing.

---

If you take the exterior derivative of both expression, you get $dP \wedge dQ = dp \wedge (dq - pdt)$, the RHS being also equal to $dp \wedge d(q-pt)$. This suggests to consider $P = p$ and $Q = q-pt$, which yields

$$ PdQ - pdq = p(dq - pdt - tdp) - pdq = - p^2dt - tpdp \, .$$

Hence $dT = PdQ - pdq + \frac{p^2}{2}dt = - \frac{p^2}{2}dt - tpdp = - d \left( \frac{p^2t}{2} \right)$, which suggests to set $T = - \frac{p^2t}{2}$. In that way, we got a map

$$ \Psi_3 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 : (p,q,t) \mapsto (P, Q, T) = (p, q-pt, - \frac{p^2}{2}t ) \, . $$

This map is not a diffeomorphism either, because it is not injective on the plane $p = 0$. But this map has a clearer meaning from a physical viewpoint which 'explains' why $p=0$ is special: it is related to the free motion of a particle (of mass $m=1$) whose momentum is $p$ and whose energy is $E = p^2/2$. The map $\Psi_3$ corresponds more or less to a coordinates system which 'follows' the particle of momentum $p$. If $p=0$, the particle is at rest, so its position at any given time is its position at $t=0$, hence this description can not be 'injective' when time is in the picture.